# Apache-libcloud raises 403 for Azure Blob Storage

Tags: python, azure, libcloud

I have a celery task which copies data from one azure container to another using apache libcloud.

Task works fine but after some time I get 403 error.(For example task copies 50 files and then suddenly raises 403)

What could be the problem?

```
python3.8
apache-libcloud==3.3.1
celery==5.0.5
```

Comment: This error could be due to the larger file size. "The maximum file size currently supported by the Azure Storage driver is 256 MB. Uploading larger file sizes will require a code change in libcloud." You can refer to [Upload large file to Azure Blobs](https://github.com/apache/libcloud/issues/1399#issuecomment-570704353)

Comment: Thank you @DeepDave-MT for your answer, I found error cause is file size, but not large file, the file I am trying to copy was an empty file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you [kamoloff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7108319/kamoloff). As you mentioned in the comment, the cause of the **403 error** was `trying to copy an empty file`.

Alternatively, **403 error** also occurs when there is a `larger file size`.

> "The maximum file size currently supported by the Azure Storage driver is 256 MB. Uploading larger file sizes will require a code change in libcloud."

Reference: [Upload large file to Azure Blobs](https://github.com/apache/libcloud/issues/1399#issuecomment-570704353)